# Android: One ProgressBar with two AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, progress-bar

i have two AsyncTasks (subclass of `MainActivity`) which download some data simaultaniously. they are called by

`new LoadData(url).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);`

I want them both to update a `ProgressBar` but I cant think of a way to `setProgress` from two simultaneous threads so that each thread contributes 50% of the progress.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static double staticvariable = 0;
    private ProgressBar progbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        progbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

        new LoadData("http://stackoverflow.com")
                .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
        new LoadData("http://stackoverflow.com")
                .executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    }

    private class LoadData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        private String weburl;

        public LoadData(String url) {
            this.weburl = url;
            System.out.println("Starting Download");
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            System.out.println("point 1");
            URLConnection conn = null;
            URL url = null;
            try {
                url = new URL(weburl);
                conn = url.openConnection();
                conn.connect();
                InputStream in = null;
                in = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
                int fileSize = conn.getContentLength();
                double taskProgress;
                int count;
                byte buffer[] = new byte[1024];
                while ((count = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    taskProgress = 50 * ((double) count) / ((double) fileSize);
                    staticvariable += taskProgress;
                    progbar.setProgress((int) staticvariable);
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            System.out.println("finished at " + (int) staticvariable + "%");
            return null;

        }
    }
}
```

I think the solution lies with using a static variable incrementing itself by `count/fileSize` as shown above but i get some strange results. At the end of each download i print the percent completion to the console i get:

> finished at 916%

and

> finished at 926%

I dont have a clue where these numbers are from. Any ideas?

---

**Edit**
Running only one AsyncTask outputs:

> finished at 447%

Comment: Did you try executing only one AsyncTask and check if the numbers make more sense?
I suspect you have a  mistake in your staticvariable incrementation.

Comment: @Udil Yeh doing only one outputs an incorrect progress too (see edit)

Comment: Try changing staticvariable += taskProgress to staticvariable = taskProgress and run only one AsyncTask, just to check if it's really the problem.

Comment: @Udil It finishes at 1% if i do that..

Comment: Well the incremntation is OK, you should use staticvariable += taskProgres. I think the easiest way is just to test your code in debug mode. I just checked it with a file on my server, and the result was perfect (also I would print the value of the fileSize variable).

Comment: @clarisharrison I would also check the result with a static file on a server.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple (no code included, just algorithm):

1. Start by setting the maximum of your progress to 0.
2. When any of your asynctasks get their own max value, increment the maximum of the progress by this value.
3. Now as each of the asynctasks finish some of their work, increment the progress current value by that amount.
4. When all of your asynctasks are done, the amount of work done will sum up to the sum of each asynctask's maximum value and you will get a 100% progress.

---

As a side note, for this to be perfectly perfect, you probably need to set the maximum progress to the sum of each individual maximums before starting the actual work. However, this is a side note and can be discarded.